# How do I persist environment in a build within Jenkins Pipeline build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I need to persist some build information within its enviroment variables as I did it before in a POFP (plain old freestyle project) with EnvInject action.
The purpose is to be able to read them within other jobs.

I was under impression that in Jenkins Pipeline this comes out of the box.

Say, I have this Pipeline code:

```
AAA = '123'
env.BBB = '123'
def CCC = '123'

node('local_devkit'){
    DDD = '123'
    env.EEE = '123'
}
```

I ran this job and got a build. Then from the Jenkins Groovy Console I tried to access its environment:

```
b = Jenkins.instance.getItem('test').getBuildByNumber(1)
println b.environment
println b.envVars
```

I could see some automatic variables there like BUILD_NUMBER or JOB_URL.
The problem is that I want to access my custom variables created in job runtime:  AAA, BBB,... etc from my example.

Even the trick with adding a new ParametersAction doesn't help as the parameters are accessed differently in Jenkins Pipeline.

```
pa = new ParametersAction([
    new StringParameterValue("QWERTY", 'AAAA')
])
currentBuild.rawBuild.addAction(pa)
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your variables *are* being stored, though not I think accessible via the APIs you called. Exported via build REST, or via `EnvAction` in Java, or as `.buildVariables` in upstream Pipeline builds calling the `build` step.

Comment: Thanks for direction, I studied Jenkins Pipeline code and finally created  this snippet to print out the whole build environment including global vars (and it works both for Workflow and regular builds):
`b = Jenkins.instance.getItem('test').getBuildByNumber(15); rw = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper(b, false); println rw.rawBuild.environment + rw.buildVariables`. Can I rely on this approach? If so I will update the question with detailed answer.